# PHP/MySQL - Trying to create an array from while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Here is my code:

```
<?PHP
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `statistics` order by DAY desc");
while($rowi = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
    $v = addslashes($rowi['visits']);
    $visits = array($v);
}

echo "<h1>$visits</h1>";
?>
```

I want to create echo result looking like this:

```
"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "Jul"
```

But my code is not working. Can you help me out, i do not understand where is my mistake.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem is, that you overwrite `$visits` every iteration. So change: `$visits = array($v);` to `$visits[] = $v;` so that you **add** a value each iteration. After the loop you have to `implode()` the array, so that you can print it in a string, e.g. `echo "<h1>\"" . implode('"', $visits) . "\"</h1>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code you have to append item to array insde your while loop

```
 $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `statistics` order by DAY desc");
    $visits = array();
    while($rowi = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
    {
        $v = addslashes($rowi['visits']);
        $visits[] = $v;
    }

   echo implode(",",$visits);
```

Comment: I got this error `Notice: Array to string conversion in` when i execute your code..

Comment: I edit my answer check it, $visits it is an array you have to dump it

Comment: It works now but i do not have the final result as it must be. It have to create an echo result looking like this: `"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "Jul"`.

Comment: can you give us the column names of `statistics` please.